# How can I use an optional number of parameters in a Jersey REST method?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm new to Jersey. So, please pardon any mistake.

I'm trying to setup a simple REST ws. 
There is a method name `getConnectedMHubs` that have one required parameter `thingID` and two optional parameters: `time` and `delta`.

Is it possible to use the same method name for the two type of calls, with and without the optional parameters? 
I tried to specify two pathes but got a `ModelValidationException`, that says:

> A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method
>   GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces"
>   annotations at Java methods public ...

Code sample:

```
@Path("/api")
public class RendezvousWebService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("connectedmhubs/{mhubid}")
    public String getConnectedThings(@PathParam("mhubid") String strMHubID) {
        // ...
        return "{}";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("connectedmhubs/{mhubid}/{time}/{delta}")
    public String getConnectedThingsExtended(@PathParam("mhubid") String strMHubID, @PathParam("time") long timestamp, @PathParam("delta") long delta){
        // ...
        return "{}";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a path pattern like this:

```
@Path("connectedmhubs/{mhubid}")
```

makes the path parameter mandatory. However, you can make use of regular expressions to overcome this limitation. See this [link](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `@Path` makes the params mandatory. You can get around this with regular expressions or you can use `@QueryParam` with `@DefaultValue` to roll the two methods into one.